# How to get the same pickerview row value a second time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a pickerview with time values at which a countdown timer starts.

It all works barring one issue: If a user selects a time, then hits play, then cancels it, and then changes mind and wants to restart it at the same row, it no longer works. I think I need to get the pickerView row a second time. Can someone give me a tip for how to do this?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
    self.counter = self.Count[0].amount
}

//Mark: PickerView  
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.counter = self.Count[row].amount
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method for get selected row from UIPicker view

Swift 3/4/4.1

```
timePickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow

Answer (score 0):

You can select row in Picker with below code:

```
timePickerView.selectRow(self.counter, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```